# Linking sqlite.lib in a Visual C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite

I am following this [tutorial](https://dcravey.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/using-sqlite-in-a-visual-c-application/) to start using SQLite in a Visual C++ App.

But I've created a Windows Forms Application instead.

I added this code in my `main` function:

```
sqlite3 *dbb;
char *zErrMsg;
int rc;

rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &dbb);
```

And I get the following errors:

```
Error   2   error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" int __clrcall sqlite3_open(char const *,struct sqlite3 * *)" (?sqlite3_open@@$$J0YMHPBDPAPAUsqlite3@@@Z); calling convention missing in metadata D:\Info\visual studio\bProject\bProject\bProject.obj
Warning 3   warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000027) for 'sqlite3'; image may not run   D:\Info\visual studio\bProject\bProject\bProject.obj
Error   4   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001B) "extern "C" int __clrcall sqlite3_open(char const *,struct sqlite3 * *)" (?sqlite3_open@@$$J0YMHPBDPAPAUsqlite3@@@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)    D:\Info\visual studio\bProject\bProject\bProject.obj
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __clrcall sqlite3_open(char const *,struct sqlite3 * *)" (?sqlite3_open@@$$J0YMHPBDPAPAUsqlite3@@@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z) D:\Info\visual studio\bProject\bProject\bProject.obj
Error   6   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   D:\Info\visual studio\bProject\Debug\bProject.exe
```

I searched for about few hours to see what it means and how can I resolve them, but I found only that the library may not be linked correctly ...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Which version of the sqlite library you use?

Comment: I download the sqlite dll from http://sqlite.org/download.html for Windows and I created a library using VS 2010 Command Promt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you using native SQLite DLL in Windows Forms app. You should use .Net version of [SQLite DLL](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) instead.

Comment: @Andrei Andrey Sorry for broken link. I correct link in my answer, you can get SQLite DLL for .Net from there.

Comment: So... I've downloaded this: http://system.data.sqlite.org/blobs/1.0.96.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.96.0.exe
Now what to do ? I have no idea :D. What to include/link/etc. in my project ?

Comment: @Andrei Andrey I have no experience in work with SQLite from C++, but I think you could use [this tutorial](https://dcravey.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/using-sqlite-in-a-managed-c-cli-application/).

Comment: @kvorobiev Hiii! I'm experiencing the same problem you previously had. May I ask if how were you able to solve it? specifically the warning LNK4248. coincidentally I also followed the same tutorial you mentioned in the problem

Comment: Oww sorry I meant to meantion @AndreiDamian

Comment: well this answer worked for me. I remember there's a different version of the library for managed code and for native code. So you have to know what kind of project you have and get the right library, and link it properly.

Comment: @AndreiDamian If may I ask, so what exactly did you do to finally solve the LNK4248 warning?